# Can't get CMD Output

Tags: c#, cmd, process, arguments

So this is my code:

```
private void CheckLastLogon(string computername)
{
    string cmd = $"/C query user /server:{computername}";
    System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = cmd;
    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    proc.Start();

    string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

    proc.WaitForExit();
}
```

`output` is always `string.Empty` and I got no clue why ... (It's working in `CMD`).

Maybe cause of the `/c` in my command ? does it terminate to fast ?

Where is my error ?

---

**UPDATE 1:**
After redirecting the `ErrorOutput` I got some additional information.

I added the ErrorOutputand it's saying The command 'query' is not found

So what's the issue with my command ?

Here you see it's working in the cmd:

[image]

---

**Update 2:** If I remove the `/c` from my command it's not doing anything. If I break the debugger it's waiting at `proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();`

Some time later I get a `ContextSwitchDeadlock` ...

What is so horribly wrong about this ?

Comment: What if you remove `/C` then?

Comment: then it won't terminate somehow...

Comment: try Filename `C:\Windows\System32\query.exe` Args `user /server:{computername}`, leave the rest as is

Comment: I can find `query.exe` in FileExplorer but somehow I get a `Win32Exception` on `proc.Start()`...

Comment: ShellExecute true/false?

Comment: `false` currently

Comment: try toggling that

Comment: that does not help. Setting it to `true` is leading to an `InvalidOperationException`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for errors you need to do:

```
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
```

And then read from `proc.StandardError`.

**UPDATE 1:**

If using `cmd` as a go-between isn't working. You could try running `C:\Windows\System32\query.exe` directly as a standalone `.exe`. This avoids having to use `cmd` and all of the issues that this can cause.

So you'd be looking at something like:

```
ProcessStartInfo procstart = new ProcessStartInfo
{
           FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\query.exe",
           Arguments = $"user /server:{computername}",
           UseShellExecute = false,
           CreateNoWindow = true,
           RedirectStandardOutput = true,
           RedirectStandardError = true
};
Process proc = new Process{StartInfo = procStart};
proc.Start();
string[] output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadAllLines();
```

**UPDATE 2:**

`system32` can only be accessed by x64 programs, x32 programs get redirected to `syswow64`.

If you build for `x64` **only**, the following code works:

```
        ProcessStartInfo procstart = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "query",
            Arguments = "$"user /server:{computername}"",
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true
        };
        Process proc = new Process {StartInfo = procstart};
        proc.Start();
        Console.WriteLine(proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
        Console.WriteLine(proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd());
        Console.Read();
```

**TLDR:**

If you're trying to use a `cmd` command, don't use `cmd` as a go-between, just put it in the `StartInfo.FileName`. If that command is in `system32` make sure you build for `x64`.

Comment: I just expect to see the last logon of that maschine. Since it's working on CMD I expect no errors here ...

Comment: Then there's a problem with your command, not with how you're getting the output

Comment: I think you want `UseShellExecute = true` otherwise it's looking for a `.exe` called query rather than the `cmd` command `query`.

Comment: As soon as I enable `ShellExecute` I get an `InvalidOperationException`  I've tried that before.

Comment: Have you tried running the command directly in `cmd` to see if it runs as opposed to through your program?

Comment: Also, it might be worth just trying this: `Process.Start("cmd",cmd);` using the static version of process start

Comment: I did that ( left `/C` out): `query user /server:%COMPUTERNAME%` produces the expected output in `cmd`

Comment: @aschipfl what do you mean by `full path`?

Comment: @FelixD. I assume he means `C:\Windows\System32\query.exe` are you still having problems? Sorry, I think I may have misread your previous comment.

Comment: @JamesHughes yes it's still not working. Check my edits above pls !

Comment: Can you please try running the `query.exe` directly rather than using `cmd` as a go-between?

Comment: @FelixD. I've editted my answer to show how you can achieve this.

Comment: @Felix D. Please see my latest edit, I have tested this one and it works for me. The issue are the conditional redirects on the `system32` folder, so this will only work if you build for `x64` only

Comment: @FelixD. You're welcom